# Use Servlet to map radio button selected item which got same name but different value

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am facing one issue with the code.I want to make my code **reusable**.I am able to achieve the functionality.

I am wring the code in Servlet.This servlet have different functions .Servlet works on recursion events i.e all events go on to same servlet with different hidden values every time.
I have a bunch of radio buttons like :

```
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q1 VALUE='A'/>script<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q1 VALUE='B'/>javaScript<BR/>");
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q1 VALUE='C'/>scripting<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q1 VALUE='D'/>js<BR/><BR/>");
```

for checking one of the four radio buttons- i used checked in  INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q1 VALUE='D' checked

My question is :
I am sending the value of radio button to the servlet on every submit button click.I am able to retrieve it as well.But i am not able to assign the same value for radio button on back button click(Back Button is a Submit Button).Is there any way by which java code is used to select the radio button with value (as name is the same for every radio button).

I tried old conventional method to achieve the functionality.The code is-

```
if(q2.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
{
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='E' checked/>echo \"Hello World\";<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='F'/>document.write(\"Hello World\");<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='G'/>(\"Hello World\");<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='H'/>response.write(\"Hello World\");<BR/><BR/>");    
}
if(q2.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
{
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='E' />echo \"Hello World\";<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='F' checked/>document.write(\"Hello World\");<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='G'/>(\"Hello World\");<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='H'/>response.write(\"Hello World\");<BR/><BR/>");    
}
if(q2.equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
{
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='E' />echo \"Hello World\";<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='F' />document.write(\"Hello World\");<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='G'checked/>(\"Hello World\");<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='H'/>response.write(\"Hello World\");<BR/><BR/>");    
}
if(q2.equalsIgnoreCase("H"))
{
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='E' />echo \"Hello World\";<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='F' />document.write(\"Hello World\");<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='G' />(\"Hello World\");<BR/>"); 
out.println("<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME=Q2 VALUE='H' checked/>response.write(\"Hello World\");<BR/><BR/>");    
}
```

But this does not support code reusabilty.Can anyone help me with this functioanlity   in small code.

Thanks 
Prateek

Answer (score 0):

```
private void printRadioButton(String letter, String selectedLetter) {
    out.print("<input type='radio' name='Q2' value='");
    out.print(letter);
    out.print("'");
    if (selectedLetter.equals(letter)) {
        out.print(" checked='checked'");
    }
    out.println("/>");
}
```